# In html and css Border bottom and right stays black

Tags: html, css

I created buttons and wants the border to be green. From some reason - only the left and top border change the color. I tried to add explicitly border-bottom-color and right-border-color the it didn't help...

```css
.main-table
{
  //width: 40%;
  //margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  border-thick: 10px;
  border-color: green;
  border-bottom-color: green;
}



.sub-button{
  border-thick: 10px;
  border-color: green;
  border-bottom-color: green;
  border-right-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: calibary;
  background-color: white;
}



th, tr, td {
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
  border-thick: 10px;
  border-color: green;
  border-bottom-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table class="main-table" >
<tr>
  <td><button class="sub-button" type="button" id="reports" accessKey=0  align="middle" [routerLink]="['../../reports/historical-data']"><h4>Reports</h4><h6>Access and review daily and weekly statistics</h6></button></td>
  <td><button class="sub-button" type="button" id="documents" accessKey=0 size="lg"  align="middle" [routerLink]="['../../documentation/product-documentation']"><h4>Documentation</h4><h6>Download the latest product specification</h6></button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button class="sub-button" type="button" id="test" accessKey=0 size="lg"  align="middle" [routerLink]="['../../test-diagnostics/live-query']"><h4>Test a Number</h4><h6>Discover a numbers attributes across all services</h6></button></td>
  <td><button class="sub-button" type="button" id="ticket" accessKey=0 size="lg"  align="middle" [routerLink]="['../../support/ticket']"><h4>Support</h4><h6>Open a ticket with the XConnect Technical team</h6></button></td>
</tr>
```

Thanks!

Comment: use ```border: 1px solid green;```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `border-style:solid;` for a solid border. What you get is browser displaying its preferred `border-style` for button -- `**outset**` (a darker shadow on the bottom right edge of your button). See: https://jsfiddle.net/9txgjLzk/

```
.sub-button{
border-style:solid;
border-width: 10px;
border-color: green;
}
```

Use `border-width` not `border-thick`